# How to copy a const_iterator in C++

Tags: c++, iterator

In my header file I have

```
template <typename T>
class Vector {
   public:
       typedef T* iterator;
       typedef const T* const_iterator;

       Vector(const_iterator start, const_iterator end);

       // other stuff ...

}
```

and in the .cpp file I have

```
template <typename T>
Vector< T >::Vector( const_iterator start, const_iterator end ) : theSize( 0 ), theCapacity( 1 )
{
    array = new T[ theCapacity ];
    typename Vector< T >::iterator itr = start; // this is line 29
    for( iterator itr = start; itr != end; itr++ ){
        push_back( *itr );
    }
}
```

However the compiler is telling me

```
Vector.cpp:29: error: invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘int*’
```

How can I get around this problem while keeping the parameters as const_iterator?

Note: if it helps I'm trying to construct a Vector with elements from another Vector between start and end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see a reason here for not using `const_iterator` in the loop as well. Also, your `push_back` function should not accept an iterator, but a value.

Thus, I would rewrite the relevant part as follows:

```
typename Vector< T >::const_iterator itr = start;
for(const_iterator itr = start; itr != end; itr++ ){
    push_back(*itr);
}
```

Comment: the *itr was a mistake when I transfered to the post but the other thing worked great. Could you explain why?

Comment: @Lourr: That is because you are trying to convert a `const` iterator (an iterator which is supposed to provide read-only access to the referenced element) into a non-`const` iterator (an iterator which is supposed to provide read-write access to the referenced element). By using a `const` iterator, you are making a promise: "Through this iterator, the referenced element is never going to be directly or indirectly modified". But if it were possible to just assign the `const` iterator to a non-`const` iterator, the promise would be broken.

Comment: @Lourr: And basically the same principle is enforced by the type system when you try to assign a pointer to `const` to a pointer to non-`const`. Actually, that's what you are trying to do here (since `const_iterator` is a `typedef` for `T const*` and `iterator` is a `typedef` for `T*`)

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing `push_back(*itr)` instead of `push_back(itr)`, this will resolve your problem

Comment: though that is _a_ problem, that's not _his_ problem.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop just needs to use a const_iterator. The const-ness of the iterator applies only to it values, it can still be incremented. You may as well use the one you already have.

```
Vector(const_iterator pos, const_iterator end)
{
    for( ; pos != end; pos++ ){
        push_back( *pos );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Andy has said, you need a const iterator. If your compiler supports C++11, your code becomes:

```
template <typename T>
Vector< T >::Vector( const_iterator start, const_iterator end ) : 
theSize( 0 ), 
theCapacity( 1 )
{
    array = new T[ theCapacity ];
    for( auto itr = start; itr != end; itr++ ){
        push_back( *itr );
    }
}
```

I also have to ask: Are you sure you want to hand roll your own Vector? Do you have a good reason for not using std::vector?